# How can I change the background-color in between last li and ul?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

[image: click here to see image!]

How to change the background-color 
as you can see in above image? I want to change color after last `li` and in `ul`. I do not want to add a new `li`, just set the overall background-color for `ul`, and change the background color as mentioned in the image.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font: 76% Verdana; 
 line-height: 1.4em;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #467aa7;
}

a:hover {
 color: #80B0DA;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* Header */

.header {
 height: 110px;
 width: 758px;
 color: white;
 margin: 0 1px;
 background-color: #4279A5;
}

.header h1 {
 font-size: 2.4em;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding: 35px 0 0 20px;
}

.header h2 {
 font-size: 1.4em;
 font-weight:normal;
 margin: 10px 0 0 40px;
}

/* Navigation */

.nav {
 width: 758px;
 height: 2.2em;
 line-height: 2.06em;
 margin: 0 1px;
 background-color: #4279A5;
}

.nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid white; 
}

.nav li {
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid white;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: x-small;
 padding: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
}

.nav .selected, .nav li:hover {
 background-color: #80B0DA;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Hello</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kk.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <h2>Slogan!</h2>
 </div>
  
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li class="selected"><a href="#first">FIRST PAGE</a></li>
   <li><a href="#second">SECOND</a></li>
   <li><a href="#third">THIRD</a></li>
   <li><a href="#forth">FORTH</a></li>
   <li><a href="#fifth">FIFTH</a></li>
   <li><a href="#last">AND THE LAST ONE</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I rescinded my answer because the question I understood was not the one you wanted answered.  You should explain better what you want to happen.  I think you want to affect between the last `</li>` and the `</ul>` but that's not what you say.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to do something like this:

```css
li:last-child{
  background-color: #80B0DA;
}
```

It is not the best answer but you can solve the problem from here:

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font: 76% Verdana; 
 line-height: 1.4em;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #467aa7;
}

a:hover {
 color: #80B0DA;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* Header */

.header {
 height: 110px;
 width: 758px;
 color: white;
 margin: 0 1px;
 background-color: #4279A5;
}

.header h1 {
 font-size: 2.4em;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding: 35px 0 0 20px;
}

.header h2 {
 font-size: 1.4em;
 font-weight:normal;
 margin: 10px 0 0 40px;
}

/* Navigation */

.nav {
 width: 758px;
 height: 2.2em;
 line-height: 2.06em;
 margin: 0 1px;
 background-color: #4279A5;
}

.nav ul {
 width: 758px;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-top: 1px solid white; 
}

li:last-child {
 width: 332px;
 height: calc(100%-20px);
 background-color: #80B0DA;
}

.nav li {
 float: left;
 border-right: 1px solid white;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: x-small;
 padding: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
}

.nav .selected, .nav li:hover {
 background-color: #80B0DA;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Hello</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kk.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <h2>Slogan!</h2>
 </div>
  
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li class="selected"><a href="#first">FIRST PAGE</a></li>
   <li><a href="#second">SECOND</a></li>
   <li><a href="#third">THIRD</a></li>
   <li><a href="#forth">FORTH</a></li>
   <li><a href="#fifth">FIFTH</a></li>
   <li><a href="#last">AND THE LAST ONE</a></li>
   <li><a></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for response but no!, You change color of last child of ul.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `background-color` to your `.nav ul` style (red, for example):

```css
.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid white; 
    background-color: red;
}
```

And add this just before your `.nav .selected, .nav li:hover` style:

```css
.nav li:not(.selected) {
    background-color: #4279A5;
}
```

EXAMPLE:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font: 76% Verdana; 
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #467aa7;
}

a:hover {
    color: #80B0DA;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Header */

.header {
    height: 110px;
    width: 758px;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 1px;
    background-color: #4279A5;
}

.header h1 {
    font-size: 2.4em;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding: 35px 0 0 20px;
}

.header h2 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin: 10px 0 0 40px;
}

/* Navigation */

.nav {
    width: 758px;
    height: 2.2em;
    line-height: 2.06em;
    margin: 0 1px;
    background-color: #4279A5;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    background-color: red;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: x-small;
    padding: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
}

.nav li:not(.selected) {
    background-color: #4279A5;
}

.nav .selected, .nav li:hover {
    background-color: #80B0DA;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kk.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <h2>Slogan!</h2>
    </div>
        
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="selected"><a href="#first">FIRST PAGE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#second">SECOND</a></li>
            <li><a href="#third">THIRD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#forth">FORTH</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fifth">FIFTH</a></li>
            <li><a href="#last">AND THE LAST ONE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```